# Local user to NFS user mapping

Tags: users, nfs, nas

I have NAS with `nfs3` shared folder and a user defined in NAS and having access permissions to that folder. I'd like to mount that folder to my linux desktop via `/etc/fstab` and I would like to avoid specifying unencrypted NAS's username and password in `/etc/fstab`.

I've heard that there is such thing as user mapping, but I don't have a clear theoretical understanding of  how it works.

**Links and examples are welcome.**

While googling I found several examples: some of them were referring to defining mapping in `/etc/idmapd.conf`, others suggested to change `/etc/export`, but I still was missing some puzzle details in order to get it working.

Comment: Which version of NFS are you using? 3 or 4?

Comment: @derobert, I'm using NFS 3

Comment: what is the make and model of the NAS device?

Comment: @ron It's QNAP TS-420

Comment: I use synology, and what i can tell you from that is on the NAS in its control panel there is the `file services` settings where you enable SMB for windows, and NFS for linux.  For linux NFS the user mapping I leave defaulted, and as long as a local user account name and password on the NAS is the same as that in either Windows or Linux which is mounting the NAS, the access and permissions just work.  The exception is root in linux can't copy because of root_squash which is basic security.

Comment: https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/File_Sharing/How_to_access_files_on_Synology_NAS_within_the_local_network_NFS

Comment: so for you the local account username and password on linux desktop, make that same user account name with same uid and same password on your QNAP NAS, and within the NAS give that local user account the necessary folder/file permissions.